# How to Loop the List of LinkedHashMap and get Key and Values in JSTL

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl, linkedhashmap

My java class is returning the values like  **List>>**. In JSTL, How do I  print the LinkedHashMap Key and List .

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${myList.data}"> // Main List
    <DIV>
       <span option="1">${row.key}</span> // Getting empty key
    </DIV>

</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
what is .data if it is list ? I think .data will not come.Your loop should be like this

<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="map"> 
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${map}">
<tr><td><c:out value="${entry.key}"/></td> <td><c:out value="${entry.value}"/> </td></tr>
</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: It works. Thanks.